# Is there any way to add Google Sheet formatting to an Excel file, then upload that to Google Sheets?

Tags: python, google-sheets

I have multiple CSV files that I want to combine into one Excel file that has multiple sheets (one sheet for each CSV file).

I want to use some custom formatting like borders, conditional formatting for colors and certain cells, etc. Right now I'm downloading the CSV files separately from my server, importing them individually from the sheet, and then going through conditional formatting by hand.

What I was hoping to do is to accomplish all of this via code, have one final file ready, and then import that to the sheet so that the information appears as desired.

As of now it seems like the only way for me to do that is via the [Google Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/concepts), but I was wondering if there was a way to do that without having to use the API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just decided to make my own tool that takes care of this. Although this isn't 100% what my question is about (I asked about general CSV files, and this deals with a specific type of CSV file that is the result of [`sklearn.metrics.classification_report`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.classification_report.html)) I think the answer still applies. The GitHub repository is: https://github.com/seanswyi/sklearn-cls-report2excel for anyone who wants to see the full code and usage.

---

Basically, it's very possible to convert a CSV/TSV file to Excel and add formatting using [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) and you just have to be mindful of how you're formatting the cells and not to overwrite previous cell formatting. Also keep in mind that openpyxl's indices start from 1, not 0 like Python.

#### Setup

Let's say we have a CSV file that looks like this when loaded via Pandas:

```
          class  precision    recall  f1-score   support
0           pig   0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  2.000000
1           dog   0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  2.000000
2           cat   0.666667  1.000000  0.800000  2.000000
3      accuracy   0.333333  0.333333  0.333333  0.333333
4     macro avg   0.222222  0.333333  0.266667  6.000000
5  weighted avg   0.222222  0.333333  0.266667  6.000000
```

What we have to do is:

1. Instantiate a new `openpyxl.Workbook` object that will act as our Excel sheet.
2. (Optional) Remove the default blank sheet and create a new Worksheet.
3. Add the classification report rows to the Worksheet.

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.utils.dataframe import dataframe_to_rows


workbook = Workbook()
workbook.remove(workbook.active)
worksheet = workbook.create_worksheet(title="sheet_name")

report_df_xl = dataframe_to_rows(report_df)
for row in report_df_xl:
    worksheet.append(row)
```

We have to manually add the rows to the Worksheet. Otherwise we'll just be formatting a blank Excel sheet.

#### Borders

In this example I'll only be setting the top outermost border as an example.

```
from openpyxl.style import Border, Side
from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter


top_left_corner = Border(top=Side(style="thin"), left=Side(style="thin"))
top_right_corner = Border(top=Side(style="thin"), right=Side(style="thin"))
top = Border(top=Side(style="thin"))

outer_border_top_row = 1
outer_border_top_col = 1

top_left = f"{get_column_letter(outer_border_top_col){outer_border_top_row}"
bottom_right = f"{get_column_letter(outer_border_bottom_col)}{outer_border_bottom_row}"

for row in worksheet[top_left:bottom_right]:
    for cell in row:
        if cell.row == 1 and cell.column == 1:
            worksheet.cell(row=cell.row, column=cell.column).border = top_left_corner
        elif cell.row == 1 and cell.column == report.shape[0]:
            worksheet.cell(row=cell.row, column=cell.column).border = top_right_corner
        elif cell.row == 1 and cell.column in range(1, report.shape[1] + 1):
            worksheet.cell(row=cell.row, column=cell.column).border = top
        else:
            continue
```

#### Conditional Formatting with Colors

I like to use gradients to fill in colors according to values from a range of 0.0 to 1.0. You can do that by setting your own color rule.

```
from openpyxl.formatting.rules import ColorScaleRule
from openpyxl.styles import Color


start_color = Color(rgb="E67C73")  # White
mid_color = Color(rgb="FFFFFF")  # Red
end_color = Color(rgb="57BB8A")  # Green
color_scale_rule = ColorScaleRule(
    start_type="num",
    start_value=0.0,
    start_color=start_color,
    mid_type="num",
    mid_value=0.6,
    mid_color=mid_color,
    end_type="num",
    end_value=1.0,
    end_color=end_color,
)

gradient_grid_start_row = 1
gradient_grid_start_col = report_df.columns.get_loc("precision") + 1
gradient_grid_end_row = avg_row + 2
gradient_grid_end_col = report_df.columns.get_loc("support") - 1

grid_range = (
    f"{get_column_letter(gradient_grid_start_col)}{gradient_grid_start_row}:"
    f"{get_column_letter(gradient_grid_end_col)}{gradient_grid_end_row}"
)

worksheet.conditional_formatting.add(range_string=grid_range, cfRule=color_scale_rule)
```

---

After finishing all of the above, you can do `workbook.save("formatted_report.xlsx")` and you're done. You can also make a look through a list of report files if you want to create one Workbook with multiple reports as separate Worksheets.